# plsqldeveloper: update records in table, if a condition about the records is satisfied in another table

Tags: plsqldeveloper

i'v been working this problem for hours now, but can't get the hang of it.
i have a rather big project about the topic in school, so i provided here with a simple example. please help me understand the best approach here:

for students i have a table "Student" with info about the students, including student_id and student_birthdate.

for courses i have a table "Course" with course_id, course_name and so on.

for the grades of the students in each course, i have a "CourseStudent" table, containing: student_id, course_id, and grade, which is the grade of the student in this course.

i need to update the grades (in the "CourseStudent" table) like this:
any student that was born after 1990, i want to add 3 points to his grades, but only his grades that are above 50.

i tried cursors, loops and functions, but when i do cursors, only the cursor get updated, not the tables. when i try to loop and update, i get updates multiple times.
i can't UPDATE WHERE -boolean function- (that accept the student_id and return if it should be updated). because the language won't allow it.

any help will be appreciated
cheers :-)

Comment: Is this a PL/SQL (programming language) question or a PL/SQL Developer (desktop tool) question? Check the tag you used. Also you need to narrow it down to a specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting a COMMIT statement after the changes?